# jQuery plugin to automatically append to li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing task app on web... I have textarea and when you press enter automatically should add it to li element. Adding works but after refresh webpage and twice..

here's js

```
var form = $('#add-form');
input = form.find('#text');

input.val('').focus();

   form.on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var req = $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize()
        });

        req.done(function(data){
            if (data === 'success') {
                var li = $('<li class="list-group-item">'+ input.val() +'</li>');

                li.appendTo('.list-group')
                    .css({ backgroundColor: '#1b7abd'})
                    .delay(200)
                    .animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff'});



                input.val('').focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

index.php

```
    <?php $data = $database->select('items', ['id', 'text']); ?>
<form id="add-form" class="col-sm-12" action="_inc/add-item.php" method="post">
    <p class="form-group">
        <textarea action="add-new.php" class="form-control" name="message" id="text" rows="1" placeholder="Buy a milk, Go to the grocery shop..."></textarea>
    </p>
</form>
```

add-task.php

```
<?php


    // include

    require 'config.php';

    // add to the db
    $id = $database->insert('items', [
        'text' => $_POST['message']
    ]);

    // success
    if ($id) {
        // header("Location: '. $site_url .'/index.php");
        die('success');
    }

?>
```

Trying to figure it out for a while but without success. It worked but idk why now it doesn't. I have linked this js file and jquery file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in that i had in config.php php error package whats probably blocked js.